# Radpivotgrid Excel exporting - how to unmerge grouped items

Tags: asp.net, excel, telerik, export-to-excel, rad-controls

I am using Radpivotgrid to show some values and using the export function to export the data to Excel. But when exported, the filter data is coming in merged cells. So when I use the filter on this merged column, only 1 row is showing up (with which the filter data is displayed).

How can I export the data to Excel with filter values unmerged and copied to all the cells (column)?

This is how I am getting it now:
[image]

This is what I am looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the approach below for achieving the required functionality:

```
protected void RadPivotGrid1_PivotGridCellExporting(object sender, PivotGridCellExportingArgs e)
{
    var cell = e.ExportedCell;
    var table = cell.Table;
    if (cell.Rowspan > 1)
    {
        for (int rowOffset = 1; rowOffset < cell.Rowspan; rowOffset++)
        {
            table.Cells[cell.ColIndex, cell.RowIndex + rowOffset].Value = cell.Value;
        }

        cell.Rowspan = 1;
    }


}
```

Vía http://www.telerik.com/forums/radpivotgrid-export-to-excel-without-merging-cells

Saludos!!